# Update ios simulator to 7.0.6?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

Is it possible to update iOS simulator to the latest version of iOS? Now it is 7.0.6, but my simulator is 7.0.3, I have XCode 5.0.2 and updated all downloads in Preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has not released any further 7.0.X SDK than 7.0.3. The reason for that is because the API has not changed, and neither has behavior changed significantly enough to warrant a new SDK release. 7.0.6 in particular is only a security update and would not be applicable to the simulator at all; the simulator uses the underlying OS X infrastructure for network connections. You should wait for the upcoming OS X security fix.

You can, however, download beta releases of Xcode 5.1 with 7.1 beta SDK, and make sure your app is ready for the upcoming iOS 7.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

the simulator is definitely still vulnerable to gotofail even on macs that have been updated with the security fix. this is easily testable by using it to browse to gotofail.com on osx 10.9.2: https://twitter.com/visnup/status/444992820915363840